# Generating integers in the diagonal of an array through a condition

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to keep generating 10 by 10 arrays until the diagonal of the array consists of numbers greater or equal to 7. However the number of attempts should not increase one million. If the attempts are less than a million, that is when you print out the array in which the numbers in the diagonal are greater than 7 and the number of attempts. This is the code I have, the thing is my code always shows that number of attempts are above one million. Can someone look at the code and tell me why this isn't working properly?

```
int i, j, matrix2[10][10], attempts, count = 0; 
for (attempts=0; attempts<1000000; attempts++)
{
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            matrix2[i][j] = rand()%10;
            if(i==j&&matrix2[i][j] >= 7)
                count++;
        }
    }
}
printf("\n\nNumber of attempts : %d", count);
if (attempts >= 1000000)
    printf("\n\nNumber of attempts exceed one million :\t ACTION TERMINATED!!!");
else
{
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<10; j++)
            if (i==j&&matrix2[i][j] >= 7)
                printf("%5d",matrix2[i][j]);
    printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it on the first attemp. Replace:

```
matrix2[i][j] = rand()%10;
if(i==j&&matrix2[i][j] >= 7)
    count++;
```

With:

```
matrix2[i][j] = i==j?rand()%3+7:rand()%10;
```

And remove the retry loop.

If you for some unfathomable reason want to keep to generating and discarding, add a break condition for the case you actually succeed!

Comment: That works thank you, but what about displaying the number of attempts?

Comment: Well, it was only one attempt, and it succeeded. You can just output that.

Answer (score 0):

simple :)
the first loop will end when attempts will reach 1000000:

```
attempts = 999998; //continue
attempts = 999999; //continue
attempts = 1000000; //stop
```

and then, you are checking if attempts is greater or equal to 1000000, and it is equal :)

you should check that it is greater:

```
if (attempts > 1000000)
```

Regards,
 Kamou